# Show that the improper integral converges

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f[0, \infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, **differentiable, positive** and $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\log f)'(x) = L < 0$. Prove that $\int_0^\infty f < \infty$.

So $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\log f)'(x) = L$ implies that there's an $M$ such that for every $x>M$:$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}  < 0$$

Since $f$ is positive, this is implying that for $x>M$, $f$ is monotonically decreasing, strictly.

So I made some progress but got stuck here. We just covered Abel's/Dirichlet's tests but I can't see how to apply it here.

Help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**
Inspired by Claudeh5:

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then, from continuity, there's an $N$ such that for every $x>N$:

$$L-\varepsilon \le (\ln f)'(x) \le L+\varepsilon$$

Now, we integrate from $0$ to $x$ and get:

$$(L-\varepsilon)x \le \ln(f(x)) - \ln(f(0)) \le (L+\varepsilon)x $$
Denote $C:=\ln(f(0))$.
$$(L-\varepsilon)x + C \le \ln(f(x)) \le (L+\varepsilon)x + C $$

Finally, we take exponent:

$$e^{(L-\varepsilon)x + C} \le f(x) \le e^{(L+\varepsilon)x + C}$$

So it seems that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$. Isn't it?

Comment: The limit at $+\infty$ is necessary 0 for a function which is integrable at $+\infty$. if it is not the case, the integral diverge to $\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>0,$ consider $ (\ln f(x))/(Lx).$ Because $Lx \to -\infty,$ L'Hopital is open to us. The quotient of derivatives is $(\ln f)'(x)/L \to 1.$ Therefore $ (\ln f(x))/(Lx) \to 1.$ So for large $x,$ $(\ln f(x))/(Lx) > 1/2.$ Because $L < 0,$ we get $\ln f(x) < Lx/2$ for large $x.$ This gives $f(x) < e^{Lx/2}$ for large $x$ and again using $L<0,$ we get $\int_0^\infty f < \infty$ as desired.

Comment: You basically compared $\int_0^\infty f(x)$ to $\int_0^\infty e^{Lx/2}$ and we know that the RHS $< \infty$. right?

Comment: I showed $\int_a^\infty f \le \int_a^\infty e^{Lx/2}$ for some $a>0.$

Comment: Why can't  you start from $0$?

Comment: Because we only have that information "in the limit", i. e., for large $x.$

Comment: Oh okay.. right!

Comment: Wait a sec; How come you can use LHospital rule here?

Comment: Reread my second sentence.

Comment: You claim that if two functions behave the same (Infinitesimally) , then their anti-derivatives behave the same. What L'Hopital has to do with that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If $f'/g'$ has a limit, then $f/g$ has the same limit. That's what L'Hopital says (assuming we can use the rule, which we can here).

Comment: Yes, but it can be applied only for the cases $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$. Isn't it?

Comment: No, you only need the denominator to blow up positively or negatively - very much like its cousin, Stolz-Cesaro, for sequences.

Answer (score 2):

We can view that as $f'(x)\~Lf(x)$. Solving the differential equation obtained by replacing $\~$ with $=$ we get $ce^{Lx}$. Now this curve is indeed integrable at infinity, se if we show $f$ is asymptotic to it we are done. Certainly the ratios of the derivatives and functions are. Integrating, we get the logs will differ by $o(x)$: $\log f=Lx+o(x)$. So $\frac{f}{e^{Lx}}=e^{o(x)}$. But then $f$ is $e^{Lx}e^{o(x)}$, which is eventually at most $e^{Lx+x}$. So at least if $L>-1$, we are done. But surely $e^{o(x)}\leq e^{kx}$ for all positive $k$, eventually, so for all strictly negative $L$ we will find a $k:L+k\leq0$, which solves our problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\lim_{x \to \infty}(\ln f)' = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f'}{f} = L <0$ then  $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists x_0$,   $x>x_0$ then (integrating the inequality $|\frac{f'}{f} -L| \le \epsilon$ for x>x_0) $|\ln f(x)-Lx|\le \epsilon x$ and  so $f$ is integrable at $+\infty$ because $\exp((L-\epsilon)x) \le |f(x)| \le \exp((L+\epsilon)x)$.

(evidently we suppose $\epsilon <|L|$ )

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is integrable on $[0, a]$?

Comment: $f$ is differentiable, so there's no problem with the integrability of $f.$ However the integrability of $f'/f$ is in question.

Comment: yes, $f'/f$ may be not integrable on [0, a] but I think the important is the integrability on $]x_0, \infty[$. I have said "f is integrable at $+\infty$".